# Some images from i.stack.imgur.com images only show an error message

Tags: support, images, broken-links

Some answers in [How do you get a shell on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/178735/how-do-you-get-a-shell-on-a-mac/178736) have images that only show an error from imgur saying: "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available. imgur.com"

Is that expected behaviour or a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a side effect of  [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734):

> For all posts made on or after [August 17 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), any image urls in
>   the form of `i.imgur.com` were changed to `i.stack.imgur.com`
>   network-wide.
>
> This means, if …
>
> - your post was made on or after **August 17 2010**
> - **you *MANUALLY* uploaded something to imgur, that is, outside of
>     clicking the 'add image' button in our editor**
> - your image URL will be broken and you'll have to manually edit it
>     back to the old `i.imgur.com` form
>
> (please note this also implies *your image will disappear after 6
>   months*, unless you [happen to own an imgur pro account](https://imgur.com/register/upgrade) for your
>   own personal use..)
>
> Sorry, we assumed that 99% of users would be using the default image
>   upload support provided by the editor, so those users who deviated
>   will be affected.

It would appear that John T uploaded to imgur, but did not use the Image Uploader, hence the image was not stored under Stack Exchange's imgur account.

The bad news is that the *original* image has also been deleted, leading to a image link rot.

<sub><sub>which reminds me, I need to scour my previous posts and transfer them to Stack Exchange imgur account</sub></sub>

Comment: Note: due to this problem, I removed the screenshot, since it is broken.

Comment: At least the second screenshot seems to be recovered now for me. awesome, guys :)

Comment: When you start, it gets tedious really quick on updating those images

Comment: yeah, I can imagine. @random